# Windows 10 automatically doing doubleclick when I click only once

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, double-click, clickonce

Since a few days Windows 10 is being very inconsequent in registering single clicks. This is hugely annoying as many actions are now done twice, or a totally different action then what I had in mind.

This happens in all kinds of programs, like

- Automatically click the browser back button twice
- Automatically open folders instead of selecting them
- Select all units of a kind in Starcraft 2, instead of a single unit
- Automatically open emails in new screen in Outlook, instead of selecting them
- And this list goes on..

I have set "Open new folders on double click" in Folder Options => General.

What else can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some or most clicks register as double clicks, this is a common issue with old mice. I've seen it very often with some wireless logitech mice, but it happens to other mice as well. It is caused by faulty hardware. You can test this by using another mouse with your system, or by using your mouse on another system.

Comment: Hmm I have a wireless logitech mouse, have this one for a few years. I'll try another tomorrow and let you know. Thx!

Comment: The issue was indeed my mouse, thx guys!